# How to add products to cart from home page in magento2?

Tags: magento2, addtocart

I want to add products to cart from home page using ajax and it doesn't reload the page or doesn't redirect to any other page and the reflection i.e, count of the add to carts should be displayed properly.

Comment: May i know whether Your product contains any custom options, the product are simple or configurable products ?

Comment: can i get both the codes for simple product as well as with custom options sir?@PranayK